# Finding the Longest Palindrome (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble with the below code. I need to find the longest palindrome but my method keeps outputting nil. I'd like to solve this problem preferably with the range function... Any help and explanation on what I'm not doing right is greatly appreciated... cheers.

```
def palindrome?(string)
  idx = 0
  while idx < string.length
    if string[idx] != string[(string.length-1)-idx]
      return false
    end
    idx+=1
  end
  return true
end



def longest_palindrome(string)

  longestlength = nil
  longestpalindrome = nil
  idx2 = 0


  while idx2 < (string.length-1)

  idx3 = idx2+1 
  longpalindrome = string[idx2..idx3]
  longlength = longpalindrome.length

    while idx3 < longlength

    if palindrome?(longpalindrome) == true && (longlength > longestlength.to_i || longestlength == nil)

              longestlength = longlength
              longestpalindrome = longpalindrome
    end

    idx3 += 1

    end  

  idx2 +=1
  end

  return longestpalindrome

end
```

Comment: Can you explain better what should `longest_palindrome` do? Offering some inputs and expected outputs examples will help a lot.

Comment: Do you mean finding the longest palindrome in what? a unique string, multiples?

Comment: Just guessing for while (since I'm not sure what you want with this function), I think the condition for the second while should be `while idx3 < (string.length-1)` as well.

Comment: I mean, add to your question some inputs for `longest_palindrome` and the expected output. Three examples should be enough.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying. I am looking for the longest palindrome in a string. I am assuming all the characters are lower cased. Here are some inputs/outputs I should be expecting:

Comment: longest_palindrome("abcbd") == "bcb"
longest_palindrome("abba") == "abba"           longest_palindrome("abcbdeffe") == "effe"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more Ruby-like way of solving your problem.

```
def longest_palindrome(str)
  return "" if str.empty?
  arr = str.chars
  arr.size.downto(1) { |n| arr.each_cons(n) { |a| return a.join if a == a.reverse } }
end

longest_palindrome "rattattarrattatly"
  #=> "tattarrattat"
```

A palindrome will be found because every single-character string is one.

See [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Incidentally, "tattarrattat" is the [longest palindromic word in the Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome). It was coined by James Joyce in Ulysses, meaning a knock on the door.

Comment: What if the input is the empty string?

Comment: I think you could've just added a third line containing solely `""`, right?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, since we're adding a line anyway, I think a guard clause, which here is self-documenting, would be clearer than adding a  naked double quote as the last statement. To understand the latter the reader would have to figure out what condition would prevent the previous statement from returning. Their thought balloon may contain an empty string, but it might be just a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all anyways. I figured it out. I had to update one of the comparisons and shift the below:

```
longpalindrome = string[idx2..idx3]
  longlength = longpalindrome.length
```

under the

```
while idx3 < string.length
```

Below is the correct code:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  idx = 0
  while idx < string.length
    if string[idx] != string[(string.length-1)-idx]
      return false
    end
    idx+=1
  end
  return true
end



def longest_palindrome(string)

  longestlength = nil
  longestpalindrome = nil
  idx2 = 0


  while idx2 < (string.length-1)

  idx3 = idx2+1 


    while idx3 < string.length

    longpalindrome = string[idx2..idx3]
    longlength = longpalindrome.length

    if palindrome?(longpalindrome) == true && (longlength > longestlength.to_i || longestlength == nil)

              longestlength = longlength
              longestpalindrome = longpalindrome
    end

    idx3 += 1

    end  

  idx2 +=1
  end

  return longestpalindrome

end
```

In my original code, I declared the strings before the while

```
while idx3 < string.length
```

loop, so during the iteration, the string was not updating. Anyways, appreciate all your help.

Comment: Most Rubyists would write the method `palindrome?` as follows: `def palindrome?(string) string == string.reverse end`.

Answer (score 0):

A more ruby aproach, IMHO:

```
words = [...]
palindromes = words.select { |word| word == word.reverse }
longest_palindrome = palindromes.sort.last
```

While this is not the most efficient way to do it, I think this is more ruby-like.
You can improve on palindrome detection by lowercasing, stripping out whitespaces and so on.